Elastic Beanstalk Managed Platform Updates Suddenly No Longer Working
Since last week, all our systems on Elastic Beanstalk suddenly failed to install the latest platform update, 4.2.7 to 4.3.0, as part of a weekly managed update process. This came as an unwelcome surprise, as platform updates have been working without any issues for at least the last 36 months.
The reason for the failure is that the ec2:CreateTags permission is not available for arn/**/elastic-ip/ in the AwsElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy, which is attached to the aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role.
Adding this permission to the role resolves the issue. However, I have the following two questions:

Why does the AwsElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy not contain this permission in the first place, if it is required for the platform update?
Why is this permission suddenly required when it has not been required for at least the last 36 months? Have we missed an important update? Is AwsElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy no longer the correct policy for managed updates?


We had the same experience and found the same solution, and are also curious about what it means...

Some here. Also wandering what might fail next.

Experiencing exactly the same issue with multiple Beanstalk environments for years without issue.
We were using an older built-in policy and simply replaced it with AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy because it did - at the time - contain the necessary ec2:createTags permission.
This weekend all our Beanstalk environments suffered failures when performing the managed weekly maintenance; once again due to the missing ec2:createTags permission.
Having a look through AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy I'm surprised to see that it no longer contains this permission. This is all very strange.
Will be adding in the permission as an in-line policy to prevent further issues.
